# Quick Edit View Substitute in Modern?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have been attempting to have a section on a Sharepoint main page where anyone with modify access to that document library can easily modify the document metadata. Specifically there is a Status column that directs which stage of a review process a document is in and where it is displayed on the site.

I'm trying to make this as painless as possible for the end users. Right now the proposed process is to click the Quick Edit button, modify the column via a dropdown, and then click Exit quick edit to save the changes. Ideally, this document library web part would have a view set up that allowed access to the dropdown without having to go into quick edit, but it appears that the modern view of Sharepoint Online does not allow for the datasheet view to work correctly when used within the web part.

Is there another option to make this editing simpler?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same issue, when I create a specific datasheet view for a list and open it up, it does not open as Data Sheet View. I still have to click on the Quick Edit button. Why is this needed in Modern Design? Did you find a solution for this problem or do we have to wait for Microsoft to fix this (if ever).